# Lemonldap skin rule based on url parameter

Tags: perl

I try to configure lemonldap to use different skin based on the url.

I use this documentation :
http://lemonldap-ng.org/documentation/1.9/portalcustom

It says:

> Rule: a Perl expression (you can use %ENV hash to get environment variables, or $_url to get URL called before redirection, or $ipAddr to use user IP address). If the rule evaluation is true, the corresponding skin is applied.

I try to write a rule that return true if the $_url contains a parameter. But I don't know Perl language.

For example, if the url is http://myurl:8097/?skin=dark, I want to use the dark skin. If the url is http://myurl:8097/?skin=pastel, I want to use the pastel skin.

How can I check this with a perl expression?

I already try:

```
$_url =~ dark

$_url =~ $dark

$_url =~ /dark
```

None of this works.

Comment: http://p3rl.org/perlre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for

```
$_url =~ /dark/
```

The match operator is documented in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html). (Search for the bullet starting with `m/PATTERN/`.)

It's a poor check since it looks for `dark` anywhere in the URL. The following would be better:

```
$_url =~ /[?&;]skin=dark(?:[&;]|\z)/
```

Comment: Adjusted my answer for changes to the question.